# Where can I find substantial, up-to-date Jenkins documentation?

Tags: jenkins

So we use Jenkins at work, and I'd like to really learn how it works, particularly so I could customize our builds with Jenkins' flavor of Groovy scripts, understand what all of the build scripts mean, etc.  But I just can't seem to find any solid, up-to-date documentation.  Here's where I've looked so far:

- I've read "Jenkins: The Definitive Guide" -- this is good as far as it goes, but it's outdated (2011) and doesn't seem to cover many of the current Jenkins features
- The documentation on jenkins.io -- this is pretty minimal and clearly a work in progress
- The wiki at wiki.jenkins-ci.org -- this has more information than jenkins.io, but seems to be mostly focused articles on specific topics, without a comprehensive discussion of how it all works
- Stack Overflow -- there are a few questions on Jenkins documentation for specific use cases (e.g. writing a plugin), but as far as I can tell, none of those answers point to general, comprehensive documentation

I feel like I must be just missing something, since so many people use Jenkins -- they must be figuring out how to use it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins has a lot of plugins and generally I would google the plugin you intend to use.

I found some documentation about the pipeline plugin [on jenkins.io](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/hello-world/) and there is a lot more documentation there. If you want to accomplish something that you can't find there again try to google or ask here :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the [Jenkins Handbook](https://jenkins.io/user-handbook.pdf) very useful. I would say it's got a lot of good information packed into 150 pages.

Due to the numerous implementation possibilities with Jenkins, it makes it somewhat difficult to fully document every possible use case.